# Raise jquery draggable's "create" event

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-ui

I've been trying to figure out how to use the 'create' event of the jquery.ui draggable control. And an example as simple as throwing an alert does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Drag "create event" test</title>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css" media="all">
#pai { width:1000px; border:1px solid #ccc; position:relative; }
#filho { width:100px; border:1px solid #c00; position:relative; top:0; left:0; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){                           

    $("#filho").draggable();

    $("#filho").bind("dragcreate", function(event, ui) {
        alert("VAAAAAAAAAAAI!");
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="pai">
    <div id="filho">
        teste de drag
    </div>      
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've searched and tested but i can't seem to get even this simple example to work. as stated on [jquery draggable's web page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events), the control does indeed have a "create" method which can be invoked either by associating it during initialization on binding it later. i've tried both methods unsuccessfully.

I'm using jquery v1.4.2 and UI v1.8.1.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                              

    $("#filho").bind("dragcreate", function(event, ui) {
        alert("VAAAAAAAAAAAI!");
    });
    $("#filho").draggable();
});
```

Firt bind event, then create draggable.

#### JQuery UI Version update

This **will not work** with JQueryUI version lower than 1.8.7. So you also need to upgrade your JQueryUI version to a newer one. As noted by [Frédéric Hamidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464709/fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-hamidi) in the answer comments.

Comment: +1, but note it still doesn't work with jQuery UI < 1.8.7. See test fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/URchn/), questioner might want to upgrade.

Comment: Why not update to the latest? Maybe in <1.8.7 the wasn't dragcrate event? Maybe it works with `$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   create: function(event, ui) { ... }
});` construction only.

Comment: @lord_t, sorry, that was implied in my comment :) I only mentioned 1.8.7 because it's the earliest version available in jsFiddle that supports the `dragcreate` event.

Comment: So you answered yourself:> @Frederic_Hamidi

Comment: @lord_t, I might have answered the `please upgrade your toolkit` part of the question, but you did answer the `don't bind an event after it's already occurred` part, which is undoubtedly more important :)

Comment: Did you try the `$( ".selector" ).draggable({ create: function(event, ui) { ... } });`?

Comment: You have errors in your fiddle example, but that no matter. Maybe before 1.8.7 was error in jquery-ui.

Comment: thanks everyone. upgrading + moving the bind expression solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add your function in the draggable intitializer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){                           

    $("#filho").draggable({
create: onCreate
});

function onCreate(event, ui){
alert("VAAAAAAAAAAAI!");
}


});
</script>
```

This should give the same result that you require

Comment: hey oliver. indeed it does give me the same results, though I had to **upgrade** first because my jquery-ui version was a bit old.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the only things that are missing are the correct references for the required JS. =)

Add:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Instead of:

`<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

I took your code and switched the JS references. It worked!

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Gabriel... The issue has been solved by upgrading the jquery version, as stated in the comments. It would not work with Jquery UI version less than 1.8.7. In your example you use the 1.11 version, which should work fine and therefore mislead you into thinking the problem were the references.